# when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'. For example: when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles)

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I am writing a unit test method for one of the adapters:

```
  @Test
  void findAllWrongCredentials() throws IOException {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory defaultSftpSessionFactory = mock(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.class);
    SftpSession sftpSession = mock(SftpSession.class);
    Dummy dummy = mock(Dummy.class);
    URI uri = mock(URI.class);

    String filter = "*.txt";
    String dummyPath = "/download";

    given(dummyAdapter.getFactory(dummy, uri))
        .willReturn(Mono.just(defaultSftpSessionFactory));
    given(defaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession()).willThrow(new IllegalStateException("error"));
    given(sftpSession.list(uri.getPath() + dummyPath)).willReturn(lsEntries);

    StepVerifier.create(dummyAdapter.findAll(stagingArea, filter, dummyPath, uri))
        .expectSubscription()
        .expectError(FileServerConnectionException.class)
        .verify();
  }
```

I get an error at line: `given(dummyAdapter.getFactory(stagingArea, uri)).willReturn(Mono.just(defaultSftpSessionFactory));`

This is the method I am trying to mock:

```
Mono<DefaultSftpSessionFactory> getFactory(Dummy dummy, URI uri) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
      DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
      factory.setHost(uri.getHost());
      if (uri.getPort() != -1) {
        factory.setPort(uri.getPort());
      }
      factory.setUser(dummy.getUsername());
      factory.setPassword(dummy.getPassword());
      factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
      return factory;
    });
  }
```

I receive this error:
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:

1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

Comment: Was dummyAdapter properly mocked?

Comment: I am using @InjectMocks there. That is the class I am supposed to test.

Comment: If dummyAdapter is the real class that you test, why would you want its method to return mocked values?

Comment: True. Thanks a lot.